# VBA - Insert a new row when cell contains data, and copy one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with data populated.
My goal is to insert a new row when data is entered into column 'S'
When inserting the new row, copy the value in column 'D' from the row above and paste into the new column.

This is what I've got to so far... I can add the row, but I can't seem to copy the cell in column D to paste as value in the new row... Thank you!

```
Sub InsertBlankRowsBasedOnCellValue()

    Dim Col As Variant
    Dim BlankRows As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim Col2 As Variant
    Dim StartRow As Long

        Col = "S"
        Col2 = "D"
        StartRow = 3
        BlankRows = 1

            LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            With ActiveSheet
            
For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1

If .Cells(R, Col) <> "" Then
.Cells(R, Col2).Copy
Range("D" & R).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End If
Next R
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Not clear what you want to do: If you have a real table, why insert a sheet row? If you enter something in column S that cell will not be blank. So, what happens to your new entry which triggers the new row elsewhere?  Will the new row be at the end of the table?

Comment: If you type something in the row below a real table a new row will be added to the table automatically and all you would need to do is get the value in column D from the row above.